# Classes are not displaying properly when using php to detect browser and redirect

Tags: php, css, html

The code used in in index.php at the main directory is given below, detect.php is used to detect the browser used. There are 3 directories in the main directory for mobile, smartphone and web. $browser_t is the return from detect.php Everything works fine but when I load the site from any device say pc or mobile the display is like this if i load from maindirectory:

[image]

when i load the directory directly say, maindirectory/web/ then the display is like this, can you suggest where the problem might be?

[image]

Sorry for my bad english

```
<?php 
include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";
if ($page_name=='') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/index.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='technology.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/technology.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='blog.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/blog.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='about.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/about.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='single-page.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/single-page.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='404.html') {
    include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }
elseif ($page_name=='contact-post.html') {
    include 'app/contact.php';
    }
else
    {
    include $browser_t.'/404.html';
    }

?>
```

Comment: How exactly do you redirect? My guess is that the browser can't load images from a subdirectory, because it's looking in the wrong directory. In that case, the solution would be to use absolute paths for the resources.

Comment: how should i modify my index.php which i provided here. I want the link at the browser to not change.

Comment: I'm talking about the images as shown in the screenshots. Or are they icons from a font? Make sure they use absolute paths; so not `src="sprite.png"` but `src="/path/to/sprite.png"`. Things like that.

Comment: oh ok, i will look into it and let u know in a few hours